# PendingIntent and camera

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have an Android app and I want to access the Camera from one of the activities. Besides, I want to store the photo inside the application internal directory (`data/data/package...`).

However  the camera doesn't have the permission to write in this directory. I don't want to use my own implementation of camera because I had some issues with that in the past. So I was wondering if there was any way to provide the camera with the permission it needs. I saw some way to do this by using `ContentResolver/ContentProvider` but I want to make it simpler.

Thus, I was wondering if using `PendingIntent` to call the camera instead of a classic Intent could do the work. Is it possible? Could you show me some code snippet to do that?

Here is my current code to call the camera:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "my_image.jpg");
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick thought why not try the following.  Use external storage to initially create the file with the MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT file as you have above. Then in onActivityResult rename the file to a file in private storage.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually I already thought about this in case I didn't have any other solution. However I would really like to know if using a `PendingIntent` is possible in this case.